# Why is the root function in my code not working?

Tags: c++, math

So, I recently got into programming and have decided to make a fully functioning calculator but every time I run my code and try to do the root operation I just added it just loops my whole script until stopped. This is my root function and the switch statement it is used in:

```
void Root(float x, float y)
{
    float z;
    float w;
    float q = x - 1;
    float guess = 1;

    z = y / guess;
    w = guess * q + z;
    z = w / x;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
        {
            guess = guess * z;
        }

        w = y / guess;

        z = w * q + z;
        w = z / x;
    }
    
    cout << w;
}

while (YesOrNo == 'y' && 'Y')
{
    float x, y;
    char op;
    cout << "Write the first number, the operator then the second number: ";
    cin >> x >> op >> y;

    switch (op)
    {
    case '+':
        Addition(x, y);
        break;
    case '-':
        Substraction(x, y);
        break;
    case '*':
    case 'x':
        Multiplication(x, y);
        break;
    case '/':
        Division(x, y);
        break;
    case '^':
        Power(x, y);
        break;
    case 'rt':
        Root(x, y);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "INVALID_OPERATOR\n";
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Do you see a problem with `while (YesOrNo == 'y' && 'Y')`?

Comment: Try to make the code a [example].

Comment: python and php knowledge ruins C++.  For one,  `x == a && b`,  `x == a || b` do not work in C++, expression syntax is same everywhere.  Second, quotes `' '` are for characters. `'rt'` is not a string of two characters, it's some wide character  that contains those two bytes. For strings `" "` are used and they cannot be compared directly unless you're using a class, `std::string` or similar, but `switch` operator works only for integral types.

Comment: `YesOrNo == 'y' && 'Y'` is the same as `YesOrNo == 'y' && 'Y' != '\0'`, which is equivalent to `YesOrNo == 'y'`

Comment: Take some time to learn how to use a debugger to a) see the value of variables and expressions and b) to step through your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    float x, y;
    char op;
    cout << "Write the first number, the operator then the second number: ";
    cin >> x >> op >> y;
```

This code can only accept a number followed by a single character followed by another number. There is no code anywhere to handle any other input. Since "rt" is not a single character, there is no way to invoke the root function. The code will break if you give it input it doesn't expect and two characters are input it does not expect.

If you input, say "37rt5", the "37" will be read as the first number, the "r" as the single character, and then the "t" will be read as the second number. Of course, no number starts with a "t", so that will fail.

Your code repeats the failed operation over and over. So it will simply keep failing over and over. Nowhere is there any code to handle the two characters in a row, so the code will keep not handling them.

Comment: oh...I guess I'm just that dumb